# Excel v14 to v15 Graph Fails

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I recently updated Excel for Mac from v14 to v15 and my graphs seems to be failing.

The sheet runs a macro that updates a table, which in turn updates a graph (or should).

If I manually update the numbers the graph updates, however if I run my macro it sits idle until the macro finishes and then updates the graph.

Anyone experienced the same thing? The sheet works perfectly well in v14 of Excel.

Edit: I am running Excel Mac 2016 (just to clarify) - Here's the code

```
Sub ButtonClick()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 35:
    Range("C1").Value = i
    Application.Calculate
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it help if you add `Application.Screenupdating = True` before the `Wait` line?

Comment: sorry no... it seems like the graph just isnt updating until the entire macro finished. is there anyway to force it?

Comment: I don't have a Mac here to test but if I can repro the issue at home, I'll try and get it filed as a bug, and see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: that would be amazing @Rory - thank you!